# AS3 Problem with decoding JSON data from PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flex4, json

I am able to pull JSON data from PHP into my Flex application just fine with the following bit of code:

```
public function httpResult(event:ResultEvent):void { 
    var rawData:String = String(event.result);
    trace(String(event.result)); //shows correct order
    var as3Data:Object = JSON.decode(rawData);

    for (var i:* in as3Data)  {
        trace(i + ": " + as3Data[i].unit_price); //shows incorrect order
    }
}
```

When I trace the result, I see the information I am pulling in the correct order.

> {"100":{"unit_price":"2.9567"},"400":{"unit_price":"1.0991"},"800":{"unit_price":"0.7926"},"1200":{"unit_price":"0.6911"}}  {

But, once I JSON.decode the result, somehow it re-orders the content.  And, puts the first item last.

> 400: 1.0991,
>   800: 0.7926,
>   1200: 0.6911,
>   100: 2.9567

Does anyone have any ideas on why it would be doing this?  Or ideas on how I can re-order the Object myself?

Answer (score 1):

Objects in AS3 aren't ordered.  JSON key-value pairs obviously do have an ordering (it's in the text!), but I don't think there's any guarantee it'll be kept when the JSON is either encoded or decoded.

If you've got specific ordering requirements, you should probably create a list with objects in it:

```
[
    {"100":{"unit_price":"2.9567"}},
    {"400":{"unit_price":"1.0991"}},
    {"800":{"unit_price":"0.7926"}},
    {"1200":{"unit_price":"0.6911"}}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most part Andrew's answer is right on, because yeah objects in AS3 aren't ordered. However I wouldn't create a list of objects; rather I would create a list of keys used to index into the JSON object. That way it's easy to sort the list of keys.

The code for what I'm getting at is something like:

```
var as3Data:Object = JSON.decode(rawData);
var keys:Array = [];

for (var i:* in as3Data)  {
  keys.push(i);
}

keys.sort();  //don't know the correct sort off the top of my head, sorry

for (var key:* in keys) {
  trace(key + ":" + as3Data[key].unit_price);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was going to do, but I was looking for the sort method. For each key call rawData.indexOf(key), that will give you something to use to sort.